# find previous div with class name rather than using parent().parent()....parent()

Tags: jquery, html

```
 <div class="A">
 <span class = "s">
 <button>
 <button>
  <div class="B">
 <p>
 <textarea>
 <div>
 <button class="click">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

On button Click of Class **"Click"** . I need to find  in Div class A.

What i tried

```
 $('.click').parent().parent().parent().find('span') -- Working
```

i was looking for a similar alternative in easiest way

```
 $('.click').closest('div').find('.A') -- Not working

 $('.click').closest('div').prev('.A') -- Not working
```

What is the correct approach when traversing inside multiple  and to find any class with the name

*** Note  :**  This is a sample HTML just to find a correct approach in JQUERY and not to find a syntax error in HTML

Thanks

Comment: *"Note : This is a sample HTML just to find a correct approach..."* It would only take seconds to provide an example that is valid (probably no longer than writing that sentence), and it could well matter. You're asking how to navigate a DOM structure, and showing markup that is at best ambiguous. (You probably don't really have a button containing a div containing a paragraph.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No i do have that structure. itz just that i have some confidential info and some kickstart stuffs in there. But will make sure  to do in the future. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`closest('.A')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) should do it. That finds the first element in the element's ancestry (starting with the element and then going to its parent, etc.) matching the selector.

Answer (score 0):

`parents('.A')` will look for parents only, if that is what you need

Comment: It is hard to tell form the HTML sample if div.A is a parent of the click or not

Comment: Also note that `parents` will keep looking after finding one match. Typically (but of course, not always), you want to stop with the first matching ancestor. If you want to find the first ancestor but not the current element, `.parent().closest(...)` is useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agreed, `parents('.A').first()` is probably better in this case